# C# float trouble. Why 1000000 + 0.10f = 1000000?

Tags: c#, types, double

Why

`Console.WriteLine((1000000f + 0.10f).ToString("N2"));`

print

> 1 000 000.00

but no 1 000 000.10?

When I use type "double" or type "float" less 1000000 - this problem disappears!

Comment: You are near the limit of the precision of a `float` (or `Single`). Try with `.ToString("G9")`, and you will get `"1000000.13"`. You can rely on the first seven (rarely six) decimal figures of a `float`, only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use decimal to prevent those accuracy/rounding issues.

```
Console.WriteLine((1000000m + 0.10m).ToString("N2"));
```

Reason: float has only a accuracy of 7 digits ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)) - your number has 8

Comment: Fun: There are a few "domains" where Microsoft's assumption that you can rely on 7 digits with a `float` fails. Try with `0.000986f.ToString()` and `0.000987f.ToString()`, for example. They will give `"0.0009860001"` and `"0.0009869999"`, respectively. Beware that I am using the parameter-less overload of `ToString()`; demanding more than 7 digits with `.ToString("R")` or `.ToString("G9")` is another matter (where you ask for seeing the inaccuracy yourself).

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx), float type has only 7 digits precision. One milion has 7 digits, decimal part is rounded.

Double type has 15 - 16 digits precision, so milion can have 8 - 9 digits long decimal part. Number less than one milion has less than 7 digits (without decimal part).